# Meaning of blinking red border in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've noticed that occasionally, I will see a red border appear briefly while using the Android emulator (API level 15). It seems to sometimes occur when switching between applications or unlocking the device, but a surefire way to make it appear is by opening the Camera app:

[image]

I can occasionally also invoke this behavior when opening the Messaging app:

[image]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is also available on ICS hardware (Settings > Developer > Strict mode enabled). It is indicating that whatever is in the foreground is consuming excessive time on the main application thread of its process.

Comment: Oddly, this option isn't enabled ([here's the option](http://i.imgur.com/pAzNr.png)). Is that preference overridden on  the emulator?

Comment: @PaulLammertsma: Presumably. It's possible that I am wrong, but "Strict mode enabled" gives the exact same red-border flash on hardware, which is what I am going by. This sort of stuff isn't exactly well-documented... :-(

Comment: Toggling the option seems to have no effect. I couldn't invoke the flashing with a rudimentary UI-thread-blocking application, but based on the description, your answer seems right.